# Phonegap application slows down with 11 different diagrams

Tags: javascript, canvas

**The problem:**

The problem I am encountering is that I have 11 different diagrams that are running at the same time (in the background), this slows down the whole application that is made in phonegap. I am confused and do not know what I should do in order to make the application work faster. I believe that threads are the solution or that I simply must run only one diagram at a time and hold the rest dead (dead = receive no data until selected).

**Short description of the project I am working on:**

I am basically using canvas.js ([canvas website](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/)), to navigate through 11 different diagrams that will receive random generated values individually. I am using jQuery to navigate through the diagrams. The user decides which diagram he/she wants to see, only one diagram can be viewed at a time.

Here is jQuery code that allows the user too navigate through 11 different tables:

```
$('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
    var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
     $('.active').removeClass('active');
     $('#table' + row).addClass('active');
});
```

Here is one diagram out of 11 different diagrams.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
            var dps1 = []; // TB1S1

            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("table12",
            { 
              title:{
                text: "Ethanol Content"  
            },

            axisX:{
                title: "Current Time",         

            },
            axisY: {
                title: "Ethenol Content (%)",
             },
              data: [
              {     
                type: "spline",
                showInLegend: "true",
                legendText: "Ethenol Content",
                dataPoints: dps1
              }],
              legend: {
                cursor: "pointer",
                itemclick: function (e) {
                    if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                    } else {
                        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                }
                chart.render();
                }
            }

            });

            var xVal = 0; 
            var updateInterval = 1000; 
            var dataLength = 100; 

            var updateChart = function (count) {
                count = count || 1;
            // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

                for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
                    dps1.push({
                        x: xVal,
                        y: y35
                    });
                    xVal++;     
                }; 

                // When handling real data, put dps1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 inside the if statement. 
                if (dps1.length > dataLength )
                {
                    dps1.shift();            
                }

                chart.render();     
            };

            // generates first set of dataPoints
            updateChart(dataLength); 

            // update chart after specified time. 
            setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 
    });
```

I hope this information here is understandable.

Kind regards
Dler H.

Comment: So the user only sees one diagram at a time but all 11 are running at once?  I think a good first step would be to only have the visible diagram running

Comment: I believe that is exactly what I am aiming for. But my question is how?